# How does system perform action on special dedicated keys?

Tags: assembly, instructions

Whenever we get input from user, using assembly language, the ASCII code of digit/letter stores in register 'AL'. In the same way I want to know if I press like 'Ctrl+C' , 'Ctrl+V' or 'Ctrl+X' etc what actions are performed by the system i.e.,

- how scan code is stored?
- what is the procedure?
- which registers are being used by the system?

Mainly my focus is to know the internal operations performed by the hardware on above instructions.

Comment: Are you talking about assembly programming inside an OS (Windows, Linux, Mac) or low-level as in rolling your own OS or something like that?

Comment: *Which* OS? They do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very broad terms, this functionality is defined by the keyboard routines in the BIOS.  [This document](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_20/CH20-3.html), although MS-DOS focused, provides a fairly good explanation of the low level BIOS keyboard routines.  In the standard PC BIOS as described here, you would generally need to interpret the value of the AH register which contains the [**scan code**](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html) of the keystroke.  For example, on the standard US PC-AT keyboard, the key down scan code for left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is `0x1D`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally an OS would either use the BIOS, or would trap the keyboard interrupt directly and pull make/break codes from the keyboard (assuming keyboard is in make/break mode, which it usually is, but doesn't have to be).